# Let's disconnect [reconnect]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

There are 194 questions with the tag [reconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reconnect). 5 users watch it and it has no tag wiki.

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No. Telling you the question is about "reconnecting" something doesn't seem to be useful. What should be reconnected? Many things can be connected to many things and, therefore, reconnected. The tag is ambiguous and can be used in questions related to various different themes. The "reconnection" link which binds them is too weak.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

If the question in which the tag is used is about programmatically reconnecting something, yes. However, [reconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reconnect) isn't specific and it's not possible to determine to what it's referring at first. The term "reconnect" can be used in a question about trying to reconnect to a database, but also can refer to reconnecting a microwave oven to a socket.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No. For most of the questions tagged with it, its absence wouldn't make any difference.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Certainly not. Let's take 5 examples of topics in questions with the [reconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reconnect) tag:

- [Reconnecting a ESP8266 microcontroller to Wi-Fi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68328728/esp8266-wifi-connection-lost-after-acces-point-reboot);
- [Reconnecting a Bluetooth module to a PC using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67976382/c-sharp-bluetooth-client-reconnect-is-slow);
- [Reconnecting to a websocket via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66845462/websocket-reconnect);
- [Reconnecting a Kafka consumer to an Apache Kafka server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66363519/kakfa-consumer-java-disconnects-when-server-is-down-and-does-not-try-to-reconn);
- [Reconnecting to a database in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53515068/influxdb-failed-cause-spring-application-run-failed).

As you can see, we have questions that belong to very different areas, although all of them have the ambiguous tag in question.

Should that tag be burned?

Comment: Let's [reconnect] with burnination

Answer (score -25):

a tag help orienting in the vast StackOverflow questions pool.

It helps to find questions that we can answer or are specialized in.

If some one uses a tag he wants to show, what his problems is and hopes to find an answer.

That all is true for [reconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reconnect) and therefore has every right to be kept alive.

I added a Tag info so that it is clear for what the tag exists

Examples how the tags is used

[vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) [reconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reconnect)

or

[mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) [sequlize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sequlize) [reconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reconnect)

or

[c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ftp) [reconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reconnect)

To explore it further

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

yes,  it does as the user wants to reconnect to a service

> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes. it is, as it is a programing question

> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Yes, it explains exactly what the user wants to do and has problems with it

> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Yes, the servoce mays differ or the programming language, butr all want the same thing to [reconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reconnect)

Comment: When you lost a connection and to what? Your database, internet, printer, high school classmates?  Each of these is a different kind of problem, and requires a different approach of reconnecting, having a single tag for them doesn't seem sensible. The litmus test "Can you be an expert in it" also fails, when I google "expert reconnecting" I get recruitment companies and reconnecting after a COVID lockdown.

Comment: that doesn't matter, which connection you lost, not ervy code needs a reconenction and depending onb language any technology you need different approaches, which fit nicely into that tag.

Comment: Tags purpose is to "connect[] experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories". A tag called reconnect is not a well defined category, by any metric. It's just a verb.

Comment: @Braiam that does the tag. if shows what the problem is in conjuction with other tags, so it is still a good fit

Comment: Tags are not meant to tell a story summarizing the question; that's what the title is for. The tags are for categorizing the question into buckets of various sizes, hopefully in a kind of Venn diagram of bucketry such that the overlapping area of buckets is small (yeah, stretched that analog till it broke).

Comment: Tags are not hashtags. In fact, tags are not even tags, they are categories. And each question can at most belong to 5 categories.

Comment: Tags must help to find the question you can answer or wehen you are seracjing for a solution, so your assumption wís very wrohg

Comment: No, for that there are search engines. Tags are terrible for searching solutions: there are only 5 per question.

Comment: Tags help if you want tpo help like my exampöes vb and sql server and don't want a reconnct question you can dismiss that tag and as i showed in my answer you can find better such probloems. that helps questioners and answerer specialized in that topic. I can't see why you want to dismiss topic that are running well or even if they are used rarely to be burned at all. Tags are a sign of a healthy community

Comment: re: "It helps to find questions that we can answer or are specialized in.", if I am a subject matter expert (SME) in `mysql` and/or `vb.net`, I might "Watch" those tags or conduct a search for those in order to provide my expertise. There is no SME for `reconnect`; `reconnect` is not a product, field of study or concept that is defined enough meaningful to any community on its own.  It only works to narrow down in conjunction with another tag, but then just search for the word in the content. Ditto for tags `disconnect` and disconnected`. I'd vote many x to **disconnect** the lot if I could!

Comment: @IanW i am expert in mysql and VbNet and i answered such questions before and do it occasionally for many otherlanguages c# c++ ......., so i am confident. s that it is a perfect match, there are a lot of tags out, most of us a experts in one of the popular tags, but go trough all tags and see what is ok, and when you chekcm the 195 question they all fit

Comment: @nbk, but are you an expert in `reconnect` and if so, of those tagged `reconnnect`, how many would you be able to reapond to? If it does not stand on its own, let it fall.

Comment: @IanW you don't get the point, there are many hater who like to remove as many tags as there are. And i oppose that, this tag is only a battle against those. As you can see we have differnt oppinions about what a tag actually is and its purpose and it seems we need a discussion about that too

Comment: I am certainly not a hater and surprised anyone would take takes personally, but perhaps that's just today's world where everything is labeled (tagged). Personally, I don't think it these meet the definition of a tag: "Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by [sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)". I don't believe connect/reconnect/disconnect/disconnected/re-connection are "specific" of "well-defined". Next time I run into Joel, I'll ask him what was his intent with "tags".  Until then ..

Comment: @IanW much of the trouble would have been avoided if we used categories, but if I recall correctly, digg was the fad back then and it had tags (or hashtags the #tag?).